# JFileChooser doesn't disappear after cancelSelection()

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm trying to close a JFileChooser. Could you, please, let me know why the cancelSelection method in the following snippet doesn't make it disappear after 5 seconds:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    final JFileChooser fchooser = new JFileChooser();
    fchooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
    try {Thread.sleep(5000);} catch (Exception e){}
    fchooser.cancelSelection();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The method `JFileChooser.showOpenDialog()` blocks until the file chooser window is closed

Comment: I over simplified the problem. cancelSelection is called from another thread different than the event dispatch. Using a Timer solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to do this since updates to the GUI should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

You need to start the Timer BEFORE you invoke the showOpenDialog() method.

Comment: The example is not good enough. cancelSelection() runs in a separate thread different than the EDT. Putting cancelSelection in the EDT via a Timer solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `showOpenDialog()` will not return until a selection is made or the dialog is canceled. If you want to close the dialog after a timeout, you will have to do the timing in another thread.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that you should use a Swing Timer, but if you want more logic when to disable/dismiss the dialog (for example a progressbar that should close when no more data is available), either implement a SwingWorker or use the following:

```
  public static void main(String... args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    final JFileChooser fchooser = new JFileChooser();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This is run in EDT
                    fchooser.cancelSelection();
                }
            });
        }
    } .start();

    fchooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
}
```